# Issue tracking with VOTING

Tags: bug-tracking, issue-tracking

Our company uses HP Quality Center for managing/tracking defects and other types of issues.

I would like to have either a separate system or some integration with QC that will allow VOTING for issues by developers on my team.

Is this possible to do on QC? Is it an inherent feature of some other issue tracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting is possible in [jira](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Watching+and+Voting+on+an+Issue).

Answer (score 0):

Voting on issues, bugs and the like is possible with [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com/).